# Excel macro to work on all worksheets in workbook

Tags: excel

Trying to get macro to work on all worksheets in workbook
I want to 
Copy selection to separate location in same worksheet but paste values only.

Then sort selection at the new location based on first column.

This is what I have

```
Sub SortALLsheets()
Dim wsheet As Worksheet

For Each wsheet In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
Sheets(wsheet.Name).Select
    Range("AJ4:AK1732").Select
    Selection.Copy
    Range("AP4").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Range("AP4:AQ1732").Select
    WS.Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range("AP4:AP1732"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
    With WS.Sort
        .SetRange Range("AP4:AQ1732")
        .Header = xlGuess
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With

Next wsheet

End Sub
```

I get an error on the Ws.sort line

All assistance much appriciated
thanks
Ronald

Comment: What error do you get? Please be more specific

Comment: `WS.SORT` - where is `WS` dimensioned? Are you sure this shouldn't be `wsheet.Sort`?

Comment: also, note that copying values is as easy as `Sheets("SheetWhereYouWantToPasteName").Range("A1") = Sheet("SheetToGetDataFrom").Range("A1")`

Answer (score 1):

Select is rarely needed in excel macros. Try this update.

```
Sub SortALLsheets()
Dim wsheet As Worksheet

For Each wsheet In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    wsheet.Range("AP4:AQ1732").value=wsheet.Range("AJ4:AK1732").value
    wsheet.Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=wsheet.Range("AP4:AP1732"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
    With wsheet.Sort
        .SetRange wsheet.Range("AP4:AQ1732")
        .Header = xlGuess
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With

Next wsheet

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks - I figured it out.